# pushing an element with another element

Tags: html, css

I have a `header` under which is a Container containing two moderately large images, **The problem** arises when I *resize* the page, the `header` tends to go underneath my `button-container`, *what I want it to do* is to for the `header` to push the `button-container` down

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lw0pb53d/8/

By changing the `button-containers` -> `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)` to `transform:translate(-50%, 0%)` I **kinda** managed to get it to work but then upon resizing the `button-container` element was pushed down **too much** and by fiddeling around with the margin, I got it to center but then in **portrait** mode the container was going over the header *yet again*

```css
/*Header*/

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}


/*Containers*/

#button-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 35vh;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 90vw;
  /*width: 90vw;
     height: 60vh;*/
  align-items: baseline;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0%, #fff 33%, #fff 66%, transparent 100%);
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#button-container li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Text block */

#button-container .html-text-block,
.cs-text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1), transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}


/* Logo Sizing*/

#button-container .htmllogo,
#button-container .csharplogo {
  width: 440px;
}
```

```html
<h1>-projects-</h1>
<ul id="button-container">
  <li>
    <a id="html-modal-button">
      <img class="htmllogo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/HTML5_Badge.svg/600px-HTML5_Badge.svg.png">
      <div class="html-text-block">
        <h2>HTML</h2>
        <p>My web projects</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="cs-modal-button">
      <img class="csharplogo" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/0617f4657fef12e8d16db45b8d73def73144b09f/68747470733a2f2f646576656c6f7065722e6665646f726170726f6a6563742e6f72672f7374617469632f6c6f676f2f6373686172702e706e67">
      <div class="cs-text-block">
        <h2>C#</h2>
        <p>My windows projects</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is greatly solved by inserting the *content* inside a `flex-container`

so:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="flex-container">     // THE CONTAINER //
        <ul id="button-container">
            <li>
                <a id="html-modal-button">
                    <img class="htmllogo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/HTML5_Badge.svg/600px-HTML5_Badge.svg.png">
                    <div class="html-text-block">
                        <h2>HTML</h2>
                        <p>My web projects</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a id="cs-modal-button">
                    <img class="csharplogo" src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/0617f4657fef12e8d16db45b8d73def73144b09f/68747470733a2f2f646576656c6f7065722e6665646f726170726f6a6563742e6f72672f7374617469632f6c6f676f2f6373686172702e706e67">
                    <div class="cs-text-block">
                        <h2>C#</h2>
                        <p>My windows projects</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

And remove :

```
margin-top: 35vh;
margin-left: 50vw;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/EricTalv/Lw0pb53d/16/

Answer (score 0):

Your header is a h1 element (which isn't semantically correct : h1 -> h6 should be used to display heading elements, ie. titles) and thus has it's `display` property set to `inline` by default.

Wrap it inside a div : it's `display: block` default property will push the ul downward

Comment: It seems to only work if the screen is in landscape mode, but on portrait the header still goes under

Comment: I am using bootstrap for a modal which seems to alter my H6 element, thus the outcome is vastly different, is there an alternative I could use? or is there a way to bypass the bootstrap properties?